# Storing datatype u64 in QuestDB

Tags: questdb

Apparently, the Rust Postgres library doesn't allow the datatype u64 to be stored in QuestDB. So I am trying to sneak it in bypassing it as a String to the prepared statement:

`INSERT INTO table_x VALUES ($1,cast($2 as LONG))`

However, this is resulting in an error for me too, when I pass a String for $2:

`Error { kind: ToSql(1), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Numeric, rust: "&alloc::string::String" }) }`

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The following works okay with `as`:

```rust
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Error};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("postgresql://admin:quest@localhost:8812/qdb", NoTls)?;
    
    // Basic query
    client.batch_execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rust (name STRING, value long);",
    )?;

    // Parameterized query
    let name = "abc";
    let uval: u64 = 9223372036854773000;
    let val = uval as i64;
    
    client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO rust (name, value) VALUES ($1,$2)",
        &[&name, &val],
    )?;

    println!("import finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

Note the difference with `i64` and `u64` is the following:

- `i64` is +/- `9223372036854775808`
- `u64` unsigned int is `0`-`18446744073709551615`

The data type in QuestDB for `long` is 64 bit signed int (`i64`) so
if you have values over `9223372036854775808`, you will need different handling.

**edit** for more information, see the following resources:

- [Data types in QuestDB](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/datatypes/)
- [Rust postgres types](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/0.2.1/postgres_types/trait.ToSql.html)
- [Rust i64 primitive type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html)
- [Rust u64 primitive type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html)